# What actually are Cpython, IronPython and PyPy?

Tags: python

I was googling for some demo Python code I found few sample codes which say they use IronPython, CPython and PyPy so I then searched for what they actually are and found that these are already written code arenas from where we can pick functions and use them. But I am not actually sure on how to use them in my code.
And also can I use all of them at once in my single code.

Answer (score 2):

CPython is the original implementation of the Pythn language (written in C). IronPython is an implementation of the Python language that runs on the .NET framework and PyPy is another implementation of Python using Just-In-Time compilation for faster execution speeds.

They are all Python interpreters, and for learning the language it does not matter much which one you use. I prefer using CPython, since it's pre-installed on many systems, but if you need access to .NET libraries from Python or need faster code, I guess IronPython or PyPy would make sense to use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use both and PyPy is interpreter and just-in-time compiler focused on speed, efficiency, and compatibility with CPython.

good luck